# Strange behaviour with jQuery pseudo selector :visible

Tags: javascript, jquery, jquery-selectors

I have a query that looked like this:

```
$("div.modal:visible select#DTE_Field_calculator\\.type")
```

which would attempt, in theory, to find that `<select>` tag inside of the currently visible `div.modal` element.

Unfortunately, it would **return nothing at all**, despite the DOM looking exactly as you would expect (`<div class="modal">...<select id="DTE_Field_calculator.type">...`)

If I removed the `:visible` (`div.modal ...`) filter, it successfully finds the target select tag.

If I remove the `.modal` (`div:visible ...`) class selector, it will again  successfully find the correct select tag.

But when used in combination, I receive an empty array.

The only way I am able to solve the problem was to implement the performance tip on the [`:visible` documentation page](https://api.jquery.com/visible-selector/), and change the selector like so:

```
$("div.modal").filter(":visible").find("select#DTE_Field_calculator\\.type")
```

This is sufficient, and of course more performant, but I am a little confused why the selector would not work in the first place. I see no reason why it should behave in the manner I observed.

Does anyone know why the `:visible` filter selector, in combination with the `.modal` class selector, would somehow cause the entire selection to fail? Am I missing something obvious?

Comment: That sounds like a bug; it's probably failing to skip `querySelector()`.

Comment: @SLaks I was wondering something like that too.

Comment: Could you replicate issue on jsFiddle? What is the purpose of `\\.type`, doesn't match the HTML markup you have posted

Comment: Are those backslashes used in selector for escaping the dot meta character, if so, then if I'm not mistaken, the id should be `DTE_Field_calculator.type`

Comment: @Danijel Ya, this is how should look like ID

Comment: Just wondering, are you using duplicate IDs? FYI, there is a bug still not fixed regarding `:hover` used on multiple matched elements but i'm not aware of any regarding `:visible`

Comment: The only way i'm able to replicate this issue is using duplicate IDs. BUT IDs must be unique on document context...

Comment: @A.Wolff - I'm with you. I can't replicate this issue. I would be suspicious of the markup.

https://jsfiddle.net/xb0et9fq/

Comment: @Trent Here is how I can replicate OP's behaviour, using invalid HTML markup: http://jsfiddle.net/pdncnyxb/

Answer (score 1, accepted):

To explain this 'bug', i guess you are using invalid HTML markup, using duplicate IDs.

To explain why one method fails while the second works, be aware, ID selector returns only first matched element.

This `$("div.modal:visible select#DTE_Field_calculator\\.type")` is read from right to left, matching first element with ID and then check if parent `.modal` is visible.

This `$("div.modal").filter(":visible").find("select#DTE_Field_calculator\\.type")` is searching for all elements with class `modal`, filtering the visible ones, then looking for element with ID `DTE_Field_calculator.type`.

That would explain it. So solution is to use CLASS, not ID.

Comment: I was just about to post a comment on the question, but yes *facepalm*, you are absolutely right. It is indeed a duplicate ID problem. Thank you.